# `this` is not the controller in an event handler assigned from JSView

Tags: sapui5

I have recently started with UI5, and am stuck with routing between views. I am able to route between two XML views & from XML view to JS view. However, I am not able to navigate away from a JS view.

The first view is loaded but when routing to the second view, the message on console is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'navTo' of undefined".

The method `sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this)` returns `undefined`.

Component.js:

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/UIComponent",
  "sap/ui/Device",
  "sapui5/app53/model/models"
], function(UIComponent, Device, models) {
  "use strict";

  return UIComponent.extend("sapui5.app53.Component", {
    metadata: {
      manifest: "json"
    },

    init: function() {
      UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
      this.setModel(models.createDeviceModel(), "device");
      this.getRouter().initialize();
    }

  });
});
```

Routing part of `manifest.json`:

```json
{
  "config": {
    "viewType": "JS",
    "viewPath": "sapui5.app53.view",
    "targetControl": "idPageContainer",
    "targetAggregation": "pages",
    "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router"
  },
  "routes": [
    {
      "pattern": "",
      "name": "First",
      "view": "zjs_view_53_02",
      "targetAggregation": "pages"
    },
    {
      "pattern": "second",
      "name": "Second",
      "view": "zjs_view_53_03",
      "targetAggregation": "pages"
    }
  ]
}
```

Container view:

```js
sap.ui.jsview("sapui5.app53.view.zjs_view_53_01", {
  getControllerName: function() {
    return "sapui5.app53.controller.zjs_view_53_01";
  },

  createContent: function(oController) {
    this.setDisplayBlock(true);
    return new sap.m.App("idPageContainer");
  }

});
```

First View:

```js
sap.ui.jsview("sapui5.app53.view.zjs_view_53_02", {
  getControllerName: function() {
    return "sapui5.app53.controller.zjs_view_53_02";
  },

  createContent: function(oController) {
    var oButton = new sap.m.Button({
      id: "idButton1",
      text: "Go to Next View",
      press: [oController.onNextView]
    });
    return new sap.m.Page({
      title: "Title Page 2",
      content: [
        oButton
      ]
    });
  }

});
```

Controller for first View:

```js
sap.ui.controller("sapui5.app53.controller.zjs_view_53_02", {
  onNextView: function() {
    var router = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
    return router.navTo("Second", null); // Error
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update: JS View is deprecated** since UI5 v1.90. Use [Typed View](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/e6bb33d076dc4f23be50c082c271b9f0) instead.

---

In `JSView`, keep in mind to always pass the listener object (`oController`) when assigning an event handler:

```js
// In the JS view definition, NOT within the controller:
var oButton = new sap.m.Button({
  id: this.createId("idButton1"),
  text: "Go to Next View",
  press : [oController.onNextView, oController],
});
```

In the handler, the `this` will be then your controller instance which allows accessing the router from there.

For more information, check to **documentation topic [JS View](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.89.1/#/topic/91f262ef6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070).**

Answer (score -1):

what I see in your Container View is

```
return sap.m.App("id")
```

Propably it is just a typo but I guess you need to return a *new* sap.m.App:

```
return new sap.m.App("id")
```